# How does Android LayoutInflater exactly work?

Tags: android

I know that it converts the XML layout to the corresponding layout objects.
What's the difference between the output `View` objects of these two lines?

```
Inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true)
```

And

```
Inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
```

I've seen the LayoutInflater [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) but didn't get the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the former add the inflated view directly to the container and returns the container itself. The latter doesn't add the inflated view to the container and the `inflater` returns it instead of the container. To be precise, the `inflater` returns always the root of the inflated layout. This is the `container` when you pass true as third parameter, is the root of the inflated view otherwise

Comment: Why does the latter gets the `container`? Why does it need it?

Comment: the former returns the container (the one with true). to be precise, what is returned is always the root of the inflated layout. If you pass false, the root is different, because the inflated view is not added to the container

Comment: So if the third parameter is `false`, the second parameter is ignored?

Comment: It used only for the LayoutParams

Comment: `LayoutParams` that's exactly where I stuck! How this is used for that?

Comment: @Webinan see http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#492

Comment: internally Android checks if you provided a valid container. If it is the case, the it retrieves the LayoutParams from the container and call setLayoutParams on the inflated view, only if the third parameter is false

Comment: in addition to what Blackbelt said if third param is true LayoutParams are used in `root.addView(temp, params);` see line 512 of the link i posted above

Answer (score 0):

If the `attachToRoot` argument is set to true, then the layout is directly added to the view hierarchy of the `ViewGroup`. It adds it to the layout of the container. If suppose the Container has a `FrameLayout` as the root layout. Then, this adds the inflated layout as a child of the `FrameLayout`.

If the `attachToRoot` is false, then the layout is inflated, but not added to the layout. That is, it is not drawn immediately.

It is advisable to use false. Thus you can attach this activity as and when required. Orelse, it gets attached to its root, as soon as `onCreateView()` is executed.

**If false - standalone
If true - a child of the parent**. Any event on it get transferred to the parent.